# How can I use fancyhdr to style my BibTeX's page headings?

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

I haven't yet found a solution to this problem. Before using BibTeX, I styled my bibliographies with `fancyhdr`, which worked. I was able to write it directly into the bibliography environment:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \setcounter{page}{5}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}

    \bibitem{marketing}
      Armstrong, Kotler, Saunders, Wong (2007):
      Grundlagen des Marketing,
      Pearson Education Deutschland GmbH,
      München 2007
\end{thebibliography}
```

I now switched to BibTeX. Checking the BibTeX command `\bibliography{}`, I saw that it "just" inputs text from the  `.bbl` file. There the environment definition can be found. But this does not help me.

How can I define my bibliography's headers using `fancyhdr`? If not possible, how can I define them in another way?

If you provide a fancy macro that does what I am looking for, please be so kind to tell me where I can look up those features so that I write it by myself next time. I sometimes look up commands via `\show\mycommand`. Are there more efficient ways?

**I already have the correct fancyhdr definition, but I do not know how to apply it to my BibTeX bibliography.**

I'd like to apply this ...

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

... to everything in:

```
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

I'm using `natbib`. My `fancyhdr` definitions work well for every other part of my document.

**Update: minimal working example**
It is not so minimal, but it produces what I mean.

*Please note that I use `\romanhdr` to switch to roman page numbers and a certain `fancyhdr`layout in the beginning and it works very well. How can I get it in the bibliography as well? If you compile my file and watch the bibliography, everything is different.*

**`LaTeX`file:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% DOCUMENT-SPECIFIC
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22.5cm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\newcommand{\chp}[1]{\chapter{#1}\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\newcommand{\romanhdr}
    {
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    }
\newcommand{\fancyhdr}{
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    }

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\romanhdr
\clearpage

\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\romanhdr
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\romanhdr
\clearpage
\listoftables
\romanhdr
\clearpage

\fancyhdr

\mainmatter % implies arabic pagenumbering
\chp{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\clearpage

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\nocite{mybook1}
\nocite{mybook2}
\nocite{mybook3}
\nocite{mybook4}
\nocite{mybook5}
\nocite{mybook6}
\nocite{mybook7}
\nocite{mybook8}
\nocite{mybook9}
\nocite{mybook10}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

**`BibTeX` file:**

```
@book{mybook1,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook2,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook3,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook4,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook5,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook6,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook7,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook8,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook9,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook10,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
```

**This is correct:**

[image: Correct layout]

**This is wrong:**

[image: Wrong layout]

Comment: Could you please post a Minimal Working Example demonstrating the problem? I use `fancyhdr` all the time and I've never had to do anything special to get it to work with the bibliography, whether using `bibtex` or `biblatex/biber`. So it is a bit difficult to know what problem you're facing. Is it that you wish to use a different pagestyle for the bibliography?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it immediately. I need two minutes :-)

Comment: Ok, it took more time. Please note that the headings in the first example "Abkürzungsverzeichnis" are all right, and in the bibliography there are (1) no headings and (2) wrong headings.

Comment: Someone suggested to use `@preamble{\thispagestyle{fancy}}`, but it did not work, because in the `.bbl` file that was printed before `\begin{thebibliography}` and therefore did not affect it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused by what you want it to look like. Why not just set up `plain` however you want the first page of chapters to look? Then set up `fancy` for the rest. I don't really see why you need `\romanhdr` with every chapter. That's not a good way of achieving whatever effect you want here.

Comment: @crf: Thank you for your help. Yes, now I see that it is a bit odd. I did not think of `\pagestyle`, so I kept redefining it with `\thispagestyle`. What I want is that everything stays as it is except for the bibliography. There all pages should have lowercase roman letters, like the other pages. At the moment, there is no header for the first bibliography page and then the second bibliography page has the standard fancy style.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found out that you can do what I'd like to do using BibLaTeX' `\defbibheading`, but still this does not explain how to do it with BibTeX.

Comment: So you want the first page of the bibliography styled the same way as the first page of other chapters? But you want lowercase roman *letters* (do you mean numberals?) to number the pages in the bibliography? (I assume the main parts of the text use Arabic numerals?) I'm not sure which 'other pages' the bibliography pages are meant to look like.

Comment: Incidentally, is this intended to be two-sided? If not, fancyhdr keeps complaining that the E option is useless. Also, it says the headheight is too small. What are you using the plain pagestyle for exactly? Because that makes the most sense to alter for the first page of chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I *think* that the following may do what you want but I'm not entirely clear what you want so I could be wrong about this. I take it you want the output to look roughly like this:

[image: Varying page styles]

If so, something like this should do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\newcommand{\plainplain}{%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyhead[LO]{}
      \fancyhead[RE]{}
}}
\newcommand{\myplain}{%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    }}


%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% DOCUMENT-SPECIFIC
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22.5cm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{mybook1,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook2,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook3,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook4,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook5,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook6,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook7,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook8,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook9,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook10,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\plainplain

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage

\myplain

\mainmatter % implies arabic pagenumbering
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{New Section}

\lipsum[8-14]

\clearpage
\plainplain

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\nocite{mybook1}
\nocite{mybook2}
\nocite{mybook3}
\nocite{mybook4}
\nocite{mybook5}
\nocite{mybook6}
\nocite{mybook7}
\nocite{mybook8}
\nocite{mybook9}
\nocite{mybook10}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

This works by redefining the pagestyle `plain` rather than defining additional styles which you then have to manually apply. Basically, it provides two commands to switch between two versions of `plain`. `\plainplain` covers the front and back matter, while `\myplain` covers the fancier main matter (where you want the head rule even on the first page of chapters). This also avoids the need for a separate `\chp` command. `\chapter` will do what you want automatically. That means the bibliography automatically gets the styling in place at the time it is typeset since it uses `\chapter`. An alternative would be to tell TeX to use `\chp` as the sectioning for the bibliography. But I think this method is cleaner as it avoids the need to keep reapplying page styling throughout the document.

Note that it would be better to use `geometry` rather than adjusting margins etc. directly, that you need to make `headheight` at least 15pt, and that you should either drop the `E` options from `fancyhdr`'s settings or use `twoside`. If you don't correct the headheight you will get inconsistent spacing at the top of the page.

UPDATE: To get the entire bibliography to use the same style as the first page, you could use this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\newcommand{\plainplain}{%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyhead[LO]{}
      \fancyhead[RE]{}
}}
\newcommand{\myplain}{%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    }}


%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% DOCUMENT-SPECIFIC
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22.5cm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{mybook1,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook2,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook3,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook4,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook5,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook6,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook7,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook8,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook9,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
@book{mybook10,
    title = {This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title     that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs. This is my book title that I stretch so that I get two pages of bibliography in order to show that the layout of the header differs},
    author = {myauthor},
    year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\plainplain

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage

\myplain

\mainmatter % implies arabic pagenumbering
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\lipsum[1-7]

\section{New Section}

\lipsum[8-14]

\clearpage
\plainplain
\pagestyle{plain}

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}
\nocite{mybook1}
\nocite{mybook2}
\nocite{mybook3}
\nocite{mybook4}
\nocite{mybook5}
\nocite{mybook6}
\nocite{mybook7}
\nocite{mybook8}
\nocite{mybook9}
\nocite{mybook10}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Plainer bibliography]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. This is *nearly* what I was looking for. I appreciate your personal preference, but my university has its own guidelines :-) What's missing is the last page's style. It should also only contain a lowercase roman letter. In your nearly perfect example, it has the standard fancy style. Although this is really the last bit of my problem, I haven't found a solution. The second page of the bibliography (= the last page) somehow I cannot access, as it's hidden behind `\bibliography`. Do you know how to change the last page's style to `\plainplain`?

Comment: @Tobias See the updated part of my answer. Is that what is needed? That basically applies the same style enabled by `\plainplain` for the first page of the bibliography to all subsequent pages. (If there is anything after the bibliography, you would need to change it back if that's required.) By the way, I've removed my personal preference. If this is an institutional requirement, aesthetics are simply irrelevant ;).

Comment: All right, this is fantastic. I have to look at the difference between `\fancypagestyle` and `\pagestyle`. You did a great job, thank you!

Comment: @Tobias Great! Maybe this will help: you use `\fancypagestyle` to define a page style or to redefine a page style. It doesn't actually apply that style to anything. It is just like saying 'if I ever ask for style XYZ, use such-and-such header, footer etc.'. `\pagestyle` changes the default page style for all pages from that point on which don't have a special configuration. (The first page of chapters use a non-default style unless you redefine the command. Usually, `plain`. So to change that, you'd redefine the `plain` style e.g. `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.

Comment: If you issue `\pagestyle{fancy}`, `fancy` is default. To change the default, you could either do `\fancypagestyle{fancy}{...}` (or use the other config commands provided). Or (better), do `\fancypagestyle{newstyle}` and then `\pagestyle{newstyle}` at the relevant point in the document. Maybe play around a little to see what has which effects so you get a feel for it. It is harder to explain than it is to understand it, I think!

Comment: Yes, good point. I got it now; it really is easier than I thought. What confused me most is probably that the chapter beginning uses `plain`, which is why I have to redefine `plain` when I want to change the chapters' beginnings regardless of my own styles that I could have defined. So your "define-your-own-style-rather-than-redefining-rule" applies to all styles but the ones that are supposed to change the chapter beginning. This was a great help.